# Where do I place the validation exception code in my pyramid app?

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

I have a model file in my pyramid app, and inside of that model file, I am doing automatic validation before an insert using formencode. A failed validation inside of my model file raises a formencode.Invalid exception.

I found [the following documentation](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/views.html#custom-exception-views) on how to set up a custom exception view, but I am unclear on a couple of things:

1. Where do I put the actual exception view code? This is clearly view code, so it should be in a view somewhere. Should it be in its own view file? I've pasted the code I need to place at the bottom.
2. How do I make the rest of my pyramid app aware of this code? The only obvious way that I see is to import the view file inside of my model files, but that gives me a bad taste in my mouth. I'm sure there must be another way to do it, but I'm not sure what that is.

Code to place:

```
from pyramid.view import view_config 
from helloworld.exceptions import ValidationFailure

@view_config(context=ValidationFailure) 
def failed_validation(exc, request):
    response =  Response('Failed validation: %s' % exc.msg)
    response.status_int = 500
    return response
```

Comment: Anything else you would like to know regarding this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Anywhere in your project directory. I made a new file called **exceptions.py** where I place all my HTTP status code and validation exceptions. I placed this file in the same directory as my views.py, models.py, etc.

2) That bad taste in your mouth is Python, because importing methods is the Pythonic way to go about using classes and functions in other files, rather than some sort of magic. Might be weird at first, but you'll quickly get used to it. Promise.

I want to note that in your **models.py** file, you're only going to be importing `ValidationFailure` from `helloworld.exception` and raising `ValidationFailure` wherever you want. You aren't importing the whole view function you've defined (`failed_validation`). That's why the context for that view function is `ValidationFailure`, so it knows to go there when you simply `raise ValidationFailure`

Comment: I guess I meant that it felt a little out of the ordinary to be importing a view into a model file. But if that's how it's done... Does that mean I need to import the exceptions file anywhere there might be an exception?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure what you don't like about it though, it's very pythonic to import methods you want to use. If it helps, don't think of it as importing a view, think of it as raising an exception for a situation or an action.

Comment: By the way, in the models.py file you're only importing `ValidationFailure` from `helloworld.exception` and raising `ValidationFailure`. You aren't importing the whole view you've defined. That's why the context for that view is `ValidationFailure`, so it knows to go there when you simply `raise ValidationFailure`